# Value from 2nd Row of column copied to 1st row of next column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The table looks like below.

```
DROP TABLE #TEMP
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    UVRID VARCHAR(20),  
    DynamoNo INT,
    FREQHZ INT
)

INSERT #TEMP    
SELECT '15AL78',100,10 UNION ALL
SELECT '15AL78',110,20 UNION ALL
SELECT '257T13',100,10 UNION ALL
SELECT '257T13',110,20 UNION ALL
SELECT '257T13',931,30
```

I am trying to make 1 new column say `SuprerFrez` whose value is depends on column `FREQHZ`.

For every `UVRID` group 2nd value `FREQHZ` will be 1st value of `SuprerFrez` 
and for last `FREQHZ`, `SuprerFrez` value will be zero.

Expected output with 1 new column whose value depends upon `FREQHZ` column. Order by `FREQHZ ASC`

```
UVRID   |DynamoNo|FREQHZ|SuprerFrez
'15AL78'|100     |10    |20
'15AL78'|110     |20    |0
'257T13'|100     |10    |20
'257T13'|110     |20    |30
'257T13'|931     |30    |0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you have a look at `LEAD`/`LAG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(FREQhz, 1, 0) over (partition by UVRID order by DynamoNo) as SuprerFrez
from #temp t;
```

Note this assumes that the ordering is by `DynamoNo`.  If that is not the ordering you have in mind, then you need another column that specifies the ordering.  For instance, if you wanted "insert" order, you could use an `identity` column:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
    TempID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    UVRID VARCHAR(20),  
    DynamoNo INT,
    FREQHZ INT
);
```

Then the code would look like:

```
select t.*,
       lead(FREQhz, 1, 0) over (partition by UVRID order by TempID) as SuprerFrez
from #temp t;
```